# .htaccess redirect a clean image url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I am trying to do clean URLs for images, where the url also contains a description of the image (for seo purposes).  The only important part of the file name is the start and the extension.

I am trying to get like image URLs such as:

> mywebsite.com/seo-images/**123**-some-description.jpg

to do a clean url rewrite where the image is actually located at

> mywebsite.com/uploads/**123**.jpg

file types can be .jpg or .png or .gif etc.

I also have thumbnails:

> mywebsite.com/seo-images/**t123**-some-description.jpg

to do also do a clean url rewrite in the same way and place

> mywebsite.com/uploads/**t123**.jpg

I have tried putting the following .htaccess file in the seo-images directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /seo-images/

# match all numbers upto - then get the extension after .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?-([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)\.$ /uploads/$1.$3 [R=301,L]
```

so far, no good.

I have a .htaccess file in the root that does other clean mod_rewrites.

The "some-description" can be one word or many words separated by - so basically everything after the - and before the . should be disregarded and the new filename used to rewrite using the new filename in a different directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would use rather this simpler rules set in /seo-images/.htaccess, we rewrite only if %{REQUEST_FILENAME} is neither a file nor a directory, not the inverse:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /seo-images/

# match all numbers upto - then get the extension after .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-.*\.([[:alnum:]]+)$ /uploads/$1.$2 [L]
```

Without redirect, we use only an internal rewrite, Google will always think about mywebsite.com/seo-images/123-some-description.jpg instead of mywebsite.com/uploads/123.jpg .

Or you prefer absolutely rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /seo-images/

# match all numbers upto - then get the extension after .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-.*\.([[:alnum:]]+)$ /uploads/$1.$2 [R=301,L]
```

It does this:

```
/seo-images/123-some-description.jpg => /uploads/123.jpg
/seo-images/t123-foo-bar.png => /uploads/t123.png
```

Comment: Thanks, first one worked like a dream.  The directory isn't called seo-images, just used this name to help describe what I was trying to do.